# repeating vector of letters

Tags: r

Is there a function to create a repeating list of letters in R?

something like

```
letters[1:30]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s"
[20] "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z" NA  NA  NA  NA
```

but instead of NA, I would like the output to continue  aa, bb, cc, dd ...

Comment: So you expect `letters[53]` to be `aaa`?

Comment: `rep(letters[1:26],length=N)` if you want the letters to recycle. Why do you expect `NA` but ask for a "looping list" ?

Comment: I want the letters to be unique, Carl, but thank you.

Comment: @JohnWaller, being "unique" and being as I asked are two different things. Can you confirm your response to my first comment?

Comment: I want them to repeat. But like this c("aa", "bb", "cc")... and so on. Something like what excel does to name columns once it runs out of single letters, so that each column is unique but contains a repeating letter.

Comment: Do you really want AA BB CC or do you want Excel style: AA AB AC?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not too difficult to piece together a quick function to do something like this:

```
myLetters <- function(length.out) {
  a <- rep(letters, length.out = length.out)
  grp <- cumsum(a == "a")
  vapply(seq_along(a), 
         function(x) paste(rep(a[x], grp[x]), collapse = ""),
         character(1L))
}
myLetters(60)
#  [1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"   "e"   "f"   "g"   "h"   "i"   "j"   "k"   "l"  
# [13] "m"   "n"   "o"   "p"   "q"   "r"   "s"   "t"   "u"   "v"   "w"   "x"  
# [25] "y"   "z"   "aa"  "bb"  "cc"  "dd"  "ee"  "ff"  "gg"  "hh"  "ii"  "jj" 
# [37] "kk"  "ll"  "mm"  "nn"  "oo"  "pp"  "qq"  "rr"  "ss"  "tt"  "uu"  "vv" 
# [49] "ww"  "xx"  "yy"  "zz"  "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd" "eee" "fff" "ggg" "hhh"
```

Comment: ok, I was hoping there was some slick built-in R function, but thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you just want unique names, you could use

```
make.unique(rep(letters, length.out = 30), sep='')
```

Edit:

Here's another way to get repeating letters using `Reduce`.

```
myletters <- function(n) 
unlist(Reduce(paste0, 
       replicate(n %/% length(letters), letters, simplify=FALSE),
       init=letters,
       accumulate=TRUE))[1:n]

myletters(60)
#  [1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"   "e"   "f"   "g"   "h"   "i"   "j"   "k"   "l"  
# [13] "m"   "n"   "o"   "p"   "q"   "r"   "s"   "t"   "u"   "v"   "w"   "x"  
# [25] "y"   "z"   "aa"  "bb"  "cc"  "dd"  "ee"  "ff"  "gg"  "hh"  "ii"  "jj" 
# [37] "kk"  "ll"  "mm"  "nn"  "oo"  "pp"  "qq"  "rr"  "ss"  "tt"  "uu"  "vv" 
# [49] "ww"  "xx"  "yy"  "zz"  "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd" "eee" "fff" "ggg" "hhh"
```

Comment: Sort of what I want. I will accept, if no one else comes along. Thanks.

Comment: Can you check your `myletters` function? I'm getting an error about your `init` argument.

Comment: Just benchmarked these--this is by far the fastest option here. And thanks for the edit. +1

Comment: @AnandaMahto yeah - you beat me to it -- see my benchmark results posted :-)

Answer (score 8):

#### Working solution

A function to produce Excel-style column names, i.e.

```
# A, B, ..., Z, AA, AB, ..., AZ, BA, BB, ..., ..., ZZ, AAA, ...

letterwrap <- function(n, depth = 1) {
    args <- lapply(1:depth, FUN = function(x) return(LETTERS))
    x <- do.call(expand.grid, args = list(args, stringsAsFactors = F))
    x <- x[, rev(names(x)), drop = F]
    x <- do.call(paste0, x)
    if (n <= length(x)) return(x[1:n])
    return(c(x, letterwrap(n - length(x), depth = depth + 1)))
}

letterwrap(26^2 + 52) # through AAZ
```

---

#### Botched attempt

Initially I thought this would best be done cleverly by converting to base 26, but that doesn't work. The issue is that Excel column names *aren't base 26*, which took me a long time to realize. The catch is 0: if you try to map a letter (like `A`) to 0, you've got a problem when you want to distinguish between `A` and `AA` and `AAA`...

Another way to illustrate the problem is in "digits". In base 10, there are 10 single-digit numbers (0-9), then 90 double-digit numbers (10:99), 900 three-digit numbers... generalizing to `10^d - 10^(d - 1)` numbers with `d` digits for `d > 1`. However, in Excel column names there are 26 single-letter names, 26^2 double-letter names, 26^3 triple-letter names, with no subtraction.

I'll leave this code as a warning to others:

```
## Converts a number to base 26, returns a vector for each "digit"
b26 <- function(n) {
    stopifnot(n >= 0)
    if (n <= 1) return(n)
    n26 <- rep(NA, ceiling(log(n, base = 26)))
    for (i in seq_along(n26)) {
        n26[i] <- (n %% 26)
        n <- n %/% 26
    }
    return(rev(n26))
}

## Returns the name of nth value in the sequence
## A, B, C, ..., Z, AA, AB, AC, ..., AZ, BA, ...
letterwrap1 <- function(n, lower = FALSE) {
    let <- if (lower) letters else LETTERS
    base26 <- b26(n)
    base26[base26 == 0] <- 26
    paste(let[base26], collapse = "")
}

## Vectorized version of letterwrap
letter_col_names <- Vectorize(letterwrap, vectorize.args="n")

> letter_col_names(1:4)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

> letter_col_names(25:30)
[1] "Y"  "Z"  "AA" "AB" "AC" "AD"

# Looks pretty good
# Until we get here:
> letter_col_names(50:54)
[1] "AX" "AY" "BZ" "BA" "BB"
```

Comment: I know this is an old post by now, and I gave it my vote a long time ago and don't intend to retract it, but the solution doesn't quite work. Take a look at `excel_col_names(52)` which should be `"AZ"`, or even further off, `excel_col_names(675:678)` which gives us `"YY"  "ZZ"  "AZA" "AZB"` instead of `"YY", "YZ", "ZA", "ZB"`. I suspect there is something easy that can be tweaked, but I'm not seeing it at the moment. (Also, I think there's a problem with your `stopifnot` because I can't get the function to work if it's there).

Comment: I appreciate you pointing this out. I fixed the `stopifnot` syntax error (that's what I get for pasting a running solution into an answer and then editing it :/), but I do still have an indexing problem: it works great up to `letterwrap(51)`, `"AY"`, but then `letterwrap(52)` is `"BZ"`. I'll try to fix it in the next couple days.

Comment: Gregor, your function is [in demand again](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25876755/1270695). Did you ever get around to identifying a fix?

Comment: it's base 27 omitting the numbers which have 0's (not that that's helpful)

Answer (score 3):

There is almost certainly a better way, but this is what I ended up with:

```
letter_wrap <- function(idx) {  
  vapply(
    idx,
    function(x) 
      paste0(
        rep(
          letters[replace(x %% 26, !x %% 26, 26)], 1 + (x - 1) %/% 26 ), collapse=""), "")
}
letter_wrap(1:60)
#  [1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"   "e"   "f"   "g"   "h"   "i"   "j"   "k"   "l"   "m"   "n"  
# [15] "o"   "p"   "q"   "r"   "s"   "t"   "u"   "v"   "w"   "x"   "y"   "z"   "aa"  "bb" 
# [29] "cc"  "dd"  "ee"  "ff"  "gg"  "hh"  "ii"  "jj"  "kk"  "ll"  "mm"  "nn"  "oo"  "pp" 
# [43] "qq"  "rr"  "ss"  "tt"  "uu"  "vv"  "ww"  "xx"  "yy"  "zz"  "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd"
# [57] "eee" "fff" "ggg" "hhh"
```

EDIT: failed to notice Ananda's answer before I posted this one.  This one is different enough that I'm leaving it.  Note it takes the index vector as an input, as opposed to the number of items.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the cleanest, but easy to see what's happening:

```
foo<-letters[1:26]
outlen <- 73 # or whatever length you want
 oof <- vector(len=26)
for ( j in 2:(outlen%/%26)) {
    for (k in 1:26) oof[k] <- paste(rep(letters[k],j),sep='',collapse='')
    foo<-c(foo,oof)
}
for (jj in 1:(outlen%%26) ) foo[(26*j)+jj]<-paste(rep(letters[jj],(j+1)),sep='',collapse='')

foo
[1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"   "e"   "f"   "g"   "h"   "i"   "j"   "k"   "l"   "m"   "n"  
[15] "o"   "p"   "q"   "r"   "s"   "t"   "u"   "v"   "w"   "x"   "y"   "z"   "aa"  "bb" 
[29] "cc"  "dd"  "ee"  "ff"  "gg"  "hh"  "ii"  "jj"  "kk"  "ll"  "mm"  "nn"  "oo"  "pp" 
[43] "qq"  "rr"  "ss"  "tt"  "uu"  "vv"  "ww"  "xx"  "yy"  "zz"  "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd"
[57] "eee" "fff" "ggg" "hhh" "iii" "jjj" "kkk" "lll" "mmm" "nnn" "ooo" "ppp" "qqq" "rrr"
[71] "sss" "ttt" "uuu"
```

EDIT:  Matthew wins, hands-down:

```
microbenchmark(anandaLetters(5000),matthewletters(5000),carlletters(5000),times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr       min        lq     median        uq        max neval
  anandaLetters(5000) 85.339200 85.567978 85.9827715 86.260298  86.612231    10
 matthewletters(5000)  3.413706  3.503506  3.9067535  3.946950   4.106453    10
    carlletters(5000) 94.893983 95.405418 96.4492430 97.234784 110.681780    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me do a little correction on seq "AY" "BZ". You have to rest out one letter to the previous digiletter.

```
colExcel2num <- function(x) {
  p <- seq(from = nchar(x) - 1, to = 0)
  y <- utf8ToInt(x) - utf8ToInt("A") + 1L
  S <- sum(y * 26^p)
  return(S)
}

## Converts a number to base 26, returns a vector for each "digit"
b26 <- function(n) {
  stopifnot(n >= 0)
  if (n <= 1) return(n)
  n26 <- rep(NA, ceiling(log(n, base = 26)))
  for (i in seq_along(n26)) {
    n26[i] <- (n %% 26)
    n <- n %/% 26
  }
  return(rev(n26))
}

## Retorna el nombre de columna Excel según la posición de columna
## A, B, C, ..., Z, AA, AB, AC, ..., AZ, BA, ...
colnum2Excel <- function(n, lower = FALSE) {
  let <- if (lower) letters else LETTERS
  base26 <- b26(n)
  i <- base26 == 0
  base26[i] <- 26
  base26[lead(i, default = FALSE)] <- base26[lead(i, default = FALSE)] - 1
  paste(let[base26], collapse = "")
}

## Return df's column index based on column name
## A, B, C, ..., Z, AA, AB, AC, ..., AZ, BA, ...
## buscando el número de columna en el df
varnum2Excel <- function(df, colname, lower = FALSE) {
  index <- match(colname, names(df))
  stopifnot(index > 0)
  return(colnum2Excel(index))
}
```

Here some example:

```
require(openxlsx)
table <- data.frame(milk = c(1,2,3), oranges = c(2,4,6))


table <- table %>%
  mutate(
    ajjhh = sprintf(paste0(
      varnum2Excel(.,"milk"), "%1$s", " + ", 
      varnum2Excel(.,"oranges"),"%1$s"),
      2:(n()+1)    
    )
  )

class(table$ajjhh) <- c(class(table$ajjhh), "formula")
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb = wb, sheetName = "Sheet1", tabColour = "chocolate4")
writeData (wb, "Sheet1", x = table)
saveWorkbook(wb, "formulashasnotgone.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```