# Is there a way to extend LETTERS past 26 characters e.g., AA, AB, AC...?

Tags: r

I use LETTERS most of the time for my factors but today I tried to go beyond 26 characters:

```
LETTERS[1:32]
```

Expecting there to be an automatic recursive factorization AA, AB, AC... But was disappointed. Is this simply a limitation of LETTERS or is there a way to get what I'm looking for using another function?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681785/repeating-vector-of-letters

Comment: Why does this question make me think of Excel?

Comment: Bijective hexavigesimal without a zero.

Comment: This is when lazy evaluation comes in handy.

Comment: There are additional answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269918/numeric-to-alphabetic-lettering-function-in-r    That question was marked as a duplicate after several people had already answered it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Would 702 be enough?

```
LETTERS702 <- c(LETTERS, sapply(LETTERS, function(x) paste0(x, LETTERS)))
```

If not, how about 18,278?

```
MOAR_LETTERS <- function(n=2) {
  n <- as.integer(n[1L])
  if(!is.finite(n) || n < 2)
    stop("'n' must be a length-1 integer >= 2")

  res <- vector("list", n)
  res[[1]] <- LETTERS
  for(i in 2:n)
    res[[i]] <- c(sapply(res[[i-1L]], function(y) paste0(y, LETTERS)))

  unlist(res)
}
ml <- MOAR_LETTERS(3)
str(ml)
# chr [1:18278] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" ...
```

Comment: c(LETTERS,(sapply(LETTERS, function(x) paste0(x, LETTERS))))[1:32]

I'll take this solution since it saves me from having to install additional packages and is automatic rather than having to add additional "paste0"'s.

Comment: `c(LETTERS, c(t(outer(LETTERS, LETTERS, paste, sep = ""))))`

Comment: `MOAR_LETTERS` needs some modifications. 703 to 728 are repeats. I must have MOAR.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: there are 18252 duplicates. Drat, so much for my attempt at humor.

Comment: I hadn't gotten that far yet in my scrolling. Man you are good at spotting and enumerating duplicates. Is there a function for that?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Um...`duplicated`?

Comment: I generalized your method into a function that would return N letters. `LETTERS0<-function(n){x=LETTERS;while((l<-length(x))<n){l=(l*(l+1));x=c(x,sapply(x,function(y)paste0(y,x)))}return(x[1:n])}` Usage: `LETTERS0(42) > A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ AK AL AM AN AO AP`

Comment: @AnandaMahto - There's a function for everything these days. :)

Comment: There are some holes, e.g. using Vlo's code `LETTERS0(53)` the last two. See my answer below for a fix, or  [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21689613/903061) for explanation.

Comment: Your first line could be `c(LETTERS, sapply(LETTERS, paste0, LETTERS))` to avoid an anonymous function

Answer (score 18):

This solution uses recursion. Usage is a bit different in the sense `MORELETTERS` is not a long vector you will have to store and possibly expand as your inputs get larger. Instead, it is a function that converts your numbers into the new base.

```
extend <- function(alphabet) function(i) {
   base10toA <- function(n, A) {
      stopifnot(n >= 0L)
      N <- length(A)
      j <- n %/% N 
      if (j == 0L) A[n + 1L] else paste0(Recall(j - 1L, A), A[n %% N + 1L])
   }   
   vapply(i-1L, base10toA, character(1L), alphabet)
}
MORELETTERS <- extend(LETTERS)         

MORELETTERS(1:1000)
# [1] "A" "B" ... "ALL"
MORELETTERS(c(1, 26, 27, 1000, 1e6, .Machine$integer.max))
# [1] "A"       "Z"       "AA"      "ALL"     "BDWGN"   "FXSHRXW"
```

Comment: Very nice! This is the function I originally tried to write, but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: This is some mighty fine use of first class functions.

Answer (score 13):

You can make what you want like this:

```
LETTERS2<-c(LETTERS[1:26], paste0("A",LETTERS[1:26]))
```

Answer (score 13):

Another solution for excel style column names, generalized to any number of letters

```
#' Excel Style Column Names
#'
#' @param n maximum number of letters in column name
excel_style_colnames <- function(n){
  unlist(Reduce(
    function(x, y) as.vector(outer(x, y, 'paste0')),
    lapply(1:n, function(x) LETTERS),
    accumulate = TRUE
  ))
}
```

Comment: This solution consumed all available memory then froze RStudio on my machine.

Comment: @neilfws
The same here :-(

Comment: @neilfws
I found Gregor's function much more faster without freezing RStudio

Answer (score 8):

A variant on eipi10's method (ordered correctly) using **data.table**:

```
library(data.table)
BIG_LETTERS <- c(LETTERS,
                 do.call("paste0",CJ(LETTERS,LETTERS)),
                 do.call("paste0",CJ(LETTERS,LETTERS,LETTERS)))
```

Comment: Simply by adding `[1:26]` at the end will get to what the OP want.

Answer (score 7):

Yet another option:

```
l2 = c(LETTERS, sort(do.call("paste0", expand.grid(LETTERS, LETTERS[1:3]))))
```

Adjust the two instances of `LETTERS` inside `expand.grid` to get the number of letter pairs you'd like.

Comment: This doesn't quite work. They're not ordered correctly.

Comment: I think I've fixed it, but at the expense of an extra function call. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Faster than sorting, you can just reverse the column order of the `expand.grid` result (see my answer). Adds more code, though...

Answer (score 6):

A function to produce Excel-style column names, i.e.

```
# A, B, ..., Z, AA, AB, ..., AZ, BA, BB, ..., ..., ZZ, AAA, ...

letterwrap <- function(n, depth = 1) {
    args <- lapply(1:depth, FUN = function(x) return(LETTERS))
    x <- do.call(expand.grid, args = list(args, stringsAsFactors = F))
    x <- x[, rev(names(x)), drop = F]
    x <- do.call(paste0, x)
    if (n <= length(x)) return(x[1:n])
    return(c(x, letterwrap(n - length(x), depth = depth + 1)))
}

letterwrap(26^2 + 52) # through AAZ

## This will take a few seconds:
# x <- letterwrap(1e6)
```

It's probably not the fastest, but it extends indefinitely and is nicely predictable. Took about 20 seconds to produce through 1 million, `BDWGN`.

(For a few more details, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21689613/903061)

Answer (score 5):

A little late to the party, but I want to play too.

You can also use `sub`, and `sprintf` in place of `paste0` and get a length 702 vector.

```
c(LETTERS, sapply(LETTERS, sub, pattern = " ", x = sprintf("%2s", LETTERS)))
```

Comment: Can someone type out what sapply() is doing here? I read it as applying the function sub to each letter (A-Z) produced by LETTERS, but am surprised to see pattern and x as separate arguments for sapply() rather than sub)). The solution works perfectly, just curious about the mechnics.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another addition to the list.  This seems a bit faster than Gregor's (comparison done on my computer - using `length.out = 1e6` his took 12.88 seconds, mine was 6.2), and can also be extended indefinitely. The flip side is that it's 2 functions, not just 1.

```r
make.chars <- function(length.out, case, n.char = NULL) {
  if(is.null(n.char))
    n.char <- ceiling(log(length.out, 26))
  m <- sapply(n.char:1, function(x) {
    rep(rep(1:26, each = 26^(x-1)) , length.out = length.out)
  })
    m.char <- switch(case,
      'lower' = letters[m],
      'upper' = LETTERS[m]
    )
    m.char <- LETTERS[m]
    dim(m.char) <- dim(m)

    apply(m.char, 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ""))
}


get.letters <- function(length.out, case = 'upper'){
  max.char <- ceiling(log(length.out, 26))
  grp <- rep(1:max.char, 26^(1:max.char))[1:length.out]
  unlist(lapply(unique(grp), function(n) make.chars(length(grp[grp == n]), case = case, n.char = n)))
}


##
make.chars(5, "lower", 2)
#> [1] "AA" "AB" "AC" "AD" "AE"
make.chars(5, "lower")
#> [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
make.chars(5, "upper", 4)
#> [1] "AAAA" "AAAB" "AAAC" "AAAD" "AAAE"

tmp <- get.letters(800)
head(tmp)
#> [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
tail(tmp)
#> [1] "ADO" "ADP" "ADQ" "ADR" "ADS" "ADT"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that allows you to specify the number of letters you want (eg. 5 would be A, B, C, D, and E), the length of the code (eg. 3 would be AAA, AAB, AAC, etc), the number of results you want (NA for all of them), and and separating character (eg. '-' would give A-A-A, A-A-B, A-A-C.)

```
letterCodes <- function(nletters, lengthCode, nResults = NA, sep = '') {
  a <- expand.grid(rep(list(LETTERS[1:nletters]), lengthCode))
  a <- do.call("paste", c(a, sep = sep))
  if (is.na(nResults)) a else a[1:min(nResults, length(a))]
}
```