# Create a list of sequential letters like in excel's header in R

Tags: r, dplyr

How to create a list of sequential letters like excel's column headers in R? I have 559 columns in my excel file, so I would like to create a vector of sequential letters like "A, B,... Z, AA, AB,... AZ,... BA, BB,..." etc. This is so that I can create my own data dictionary, so would like to "map" to excel's column headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case if you are interested in base R solution, you can try this:

```
all <- expand.grid(LETTERS, LETTERS)
all <- all[order(all$Var1,all$Var2),]
out <- c(LETTERS, do.call('paste0',all))
```

The out will return 702 values as vectors, I believe you want to subset them until 559, so you can write: out[1:559].

To rename your columns you can use, where data_frame is your data frame name

```
names(data_frame) <- out[1:559]
```

One important note though, I am assuming here that you only wanted column with two characters not more than that.

**A generic approach using gtools**

```
 comb <- lapply(1:3, function(x)gtools::permutations(26,x, LETTERS, repeats.allowed = TRUE))
 ## Using 3 for excel 3 combinations of alphabets
 unlist(lapply(comb, function(x)do.call('paste0', data.frame(x,stringsAsFactors = FALSE))))
```

**Some observations:**

> ```
> > out[1:50]
>  [1] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  "K" 
> [12] "L"  "M"  "N"  "O"  "P"  "Q"  "R"  "S"  "T"  "U"  "V" 
> [23] "W"  "X"  "Y"  "Z"  "AA" "AB" "AC" "AD" "AE" "AF" "AG"
> [34] "AH" "AI" "AJ" "AK" "AL" "AM" "AN" "AO" "AP" "AQ" "AR"
> [45] "AS" "AT" "AU" "AV" "AW" "AX"
> ```

Comment: The first one should be `c('', LETTERS)` right?

Comment: @MichaelChirico, I have used all the combinations then I combined with individual letters in third command. I am scratching my head though about your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 2):

num2let takes a number or vector of numbers and converts that to letter notation. Pass the sequence 1:n to get sequential output.

We also provide the inverse function lets2num which takes codes and returns the numbers.

The main advantages of this approach are that (1) it also works on input vectors which are not sequences, e.g. num2let(599) finds the letter code for columnn number 599, (2) if used with a sequence the sequence does not have to be a multiple or a power of 26, (3) it can be used with other codes and bases and not just 26 LETTERS, e.g. num2let(1:40, head(letters)), (4) no upper bound restriction to n, e.g. num2let(1e10) works and (5) both directions are provided and (6) only base R is used.

```
num2let <- function(n, lets = LETTERS) {
  base <- length(lets)
  if (length(n) > 1) return(sapply(n, num2let, lets = lets))
  stopifnot(n > 0)
  out <- ""
  repeat {
    if (n > base) {
       rem <- (n-1) %% base
       n <- (n-1) %/% base
       out <- paste0(lets[rem+1], out)
    } else return( paste0(lets[n], out) )
  }
}

let2num <- function(x, lets = LETTERS) {
  base <- length(lets)
  s <- strsplit(x, "")
  sapply(s, function(x) sum((match(x, lets)) * base ^ seq(length(x) - 1, 0)))
}
```

### Test

```
lets <- num2let(1:40)
lets
## [1] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  "K"  "L"  "M"  "N"  "O" 
## [16] "P"  "Q"  "R"  "S"  "T"  "U"  "V"  "W"  "X"  "Y"  "Z"  "AA" "AB" "AC" "AD"
## [31] "AE" "AF" "AG" "AH" "AI" "AJ" "AK" "AL" "AM" "AN"


let2num(lets)
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
## [26] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40

num2let(599)
## [1] "WA"

let2num("WA")
## [1] 599
```

### Other

I previously answered this question here [Numeric to Alphabetic Lettering Function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269918/numeric-to-alphabetic-lettering-function-in-r/44274075#44274075) and my answers there take different approaches than the answer here so you can look at those too.

Answer (score 0):

Base R one liner:

```
c(LETTERS, unlist(sapply(seq_along(LETTERS), function(i){paste0(LETTERS[i], LETTERS)})))
```