# Convert excel column names to numbers

Tags: r, function

I wanted to write a function to convert excel column-names into the corresponding number. What I have come up with so far, works only partially. That is, inputs where the lower letter comes first ("AB", AC", etc.) work fine. But it does not work the other way around ("BA", "CA", etc.). I have traced the error to the line `y <- which(base::LETTERS==x)` but I do not really understand how these boolean operators work on vectors. Any advice?

```
#so to pass excel column-names directly, this function should do the trick
LettersToNumbers <- function(input){
    x <- toupper(substring(input, c(1:nchar(input)), c(1:nchar(input)))) #parse input-string
    y <- which(base::LETTERS==x) #letters to numbers
    y <- rev(y) #reverse
    #base26 conversion:
    result <- 0
    for (i in 1:length(y)){
        result <- result + ( y[i]*26^(i-1) )
    }
    return(result)
}
```

Actually it turns out there are some more examples that are not working. Here are some, and I do not really understand what is going on.

```
> which(LETTERS==c("A", "B"))
[1] 1 2
> which(LETTERS==c("A", "C"))
[1] 1
> which(LETTERS==c("A", "D"))
[1] 1 4
> which(LETTERS==c("D", "A"))
integer(0)
>
```

Comment: what you are witnessing is vector recycling; check out what you get if you do: which(LETTERS==c("A","B","C"))

Comment: The inverse function is in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21689613/903061).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is quick and dirty, but I think it gets you what you want.  It should work for an arbitrary string length.

```
# Input: A string of letters s
# Output: Corresponding column number
LettersToNumbers <- function(s){
  # Uppercase
  s_upper <- toupper(s)
  # Convert string to a vector of single letters
  s_split <- unlist(strsplit(s_upper, split=""))
  # Convert each letter to the corresponding number
  s_number <- sapply(s_split, function(x) {which(LETTERS == x)})
  # Derive the numeric value associated with each letter
  numbers <- 26^((length(s_number)-1):0)
  # Calculate the column number
  column_number <- sum(s_number * numbers)
  column_number
}
# Vectorize in case you want to pass more than one column name in a single call
LettersToNumbers <- Vectorize(LettersToNumbers)

# Quick tests
LettersToNumbers("A")
LettersToNumbers("Z")
LettersToNumbers("AA")
LettersToNumbers("BA")
LettersToNumbers("AAA")
LettersToNumbers(LETTERS)
```

As noted in a comment above, the primary issue with your code is vector recycling, which this function avoids by using `sapply`.

Comment: Nice! I was fully convinced when `LettersToNumbers("BDWGN")`, the millionth Excel column name, promptly returned `1e6`.

Answer (score 4):

A faster and (already) vectorized alternative to the accepted solution [no need of `Vectorize`]

```
letters2numbers <- function(x){
  
  # letters encoding
  encoding <- setNames(seq_along(LETTERS), LETTERS)
  
  # uppercase
  x <- toupper(x)
  
  # convert string to a list of vectors of single letters
  x <- strsplit(x, split = "")
  
  # convert each letter to the corresponding number
  # calculate the column number
  # return a numeric vector
  sapply(x, function(xs) sum(encoding[xs] * 26^((length(xs)-1):0)))
  
}


letters2numbers("Z")
#> [1] 26
letters2numbers(c("A", "BZ", "CBA", "BDWGN"))
#> [1]       1      78    2081 1000000
```

---

Benchmark:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  LettersToNumbers("Z"),
  letters2numbers("Z")
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                   expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq     max neval
#>  LettersToNumbers("Z") 60.510 61.9065 70.23292 64.0005 67.957 262.051   100
#>   letters2numbers("Z") 20.481 21.4115 26.70360 22.3420 24.204 140.568   100

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  LettersToNumbers(c("A", "BZ", "CBA", "BDWGN")),
  letters2numbers(c("A", "BZ", "CBA", "BDWGN"))
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                                            expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>  LettersToNumbers(c("A", "BZ", "CBA", "BDWGN")) 152.669 158.721 206.97909 171.7530 220.8595 581.819   100
#>   letters2numbers(c("A", "BZ", "CBA", "BDWGN"))  30.255  32.582  42.47789  35.1425  43.9865 174.547   100
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    # Setup converter index numbers
    converter <- 1:702
    # Excel column names in order
    names(converter) <- do.call(paste0, expand.grid(LETTERS, c("",LETTERS))[,2:1])
    ExcelColumnNames <- c("A", "Z", "AA", "AZ", "ZZ")
    converter[ExcelColumnNames] # show excel column numbers
#  A   Z  AA  AZ  ZZ 
#  1  26  27  52 702
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who want converting back and forth (both in one function):
input a number (27), output letters ('AA')
input letters ('AA'), output number (27)

```
xlcolconv <- function(col){
    # test: 1 = A, 26 = Z, 27 = AA, 703 = AAA
    if (is.character(col)) {
        # codes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34537691/2292993
        s = col
        # Uppercase
        s_upper <- toupper(s)
        # Convert string to a vector of single letters
        s_split <- unlist(strsplit(s_upper, split=""))
        # Convert each letter to the corresponding number
        s_number <- sapply(s_split, function(x) {which(LETTERS == x)})
        # Derive the numeric value associated with each letter
        numbers <- 26^((length(s_number)-1):0)
        # Calculate the column number
        column_number <- sum(s_number * numbers)
        return(column_number)
    } else {
        n = col
        letters = ''
        while (n > 0) {
            r = (n - 1) %% 26  # remainder
            letters = paste0(intToUtf8(r + utf8ToInt('A')), letters) # ascii
            n = (n - 1) %/% 26 # quotient
        }
        return(letters)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer in these situations is often to use `%in%`, instead of `==`. For example

```
which(LETTERS %in% c("D", "A"))
```

produces `1 4`. They're not in the order you want though -- so, this will apply the function one by one.

```
sapply(c("D", "A"), function(x){which(LETTERS %in% x)})
```

produces `4 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Check for length of character element, then add places determined by position in LETTERS:

```
TwoLet2Num <- function(chars) { if( nchar( substr(chars,2,2)) ){ 
         res <- which(LETTERS==substr(chars,1,1))*26 + which(LETTERS ==substr(chars,2,2)) 
          } else { res= which(LETTERS==substr(chars,1,1) ) } 
         return(res)}
```