# Convert sequence of integers 1, 2, 3, ... to corresponding sequence of strings A, B, C,

Tags: r

What's a quick, scalable way to convert the integers 1 through N to a corresponding sequence of strings "A", "B", ... "Z", "AA", "AB", ... of the same length?

Alternatively, I'd be happy with something maps the integer vector onto a character vector such that each element of the character vector has the same number of characters.  E.g. 1, 2, ... 27 => "AA", "AB", ..., "AZ", "BA"

Example input:

```
num_vec <- seq(1, 1000)
char_vec <- ???
```

---

UPDATE

My hackish, but best working attempt:

```
library(data.table)
myfunc <- function(n){
  if(n <= 26){
    dt <- CJ(LETTERS)[, Result := paste0(V1)]
  } else if(n <= 26^2){
    dt <- CJ(LETTERS, LETTERS)[, Result := paste0(V1, V2)]
  } else if(n <= 26^3){
    dt <- CJ(LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS)[, Result := paste0(V1, V2, V3)]
  } else if(n <= 26^4){
    dt <- CJ(LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS)[, Result := paste0(V1, V2, V3, V4)]
  } else if(n <= 26^5){
    dt <- CJ(LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS)[, Result := paste0(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5)]
  } else if(n <= 26^6){
    dt <- CJ(LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS)[, Result := paste0(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6)]
  } else{
    stop("n too large")
  }

  return(dt$Result[1:n])
}

myfunc(10)
```

Comment: @Procrastinatus_Maximus I'd like to point out that my question is not the same as the one flagged as a duplicate.  I'm looking to convert the number 28 to "AB" whereas the flagged question looks to convert 28 to "BB" (i.e. it does letter *repeats*).  The issue with the latter is that numbers > 1M get mapped to big strings of text and I'm tying to keep things concise.

Comment: unfortunately reopening questions is 5 times harder than closing them. or is it 3x?

Comment: This answer seem to do what you want exactly http://stackoverflow.com/a/21689613/3001626. Not sure regarding efficiency though

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks, that's what I'm looking for but it's not as efficient as my best effort so far which is just using `data.table`'s `CJ` method combined with 5 hard-coded if-else statements determining how many copies of LETTERS to cross join

Comment: You could add that to the question. If someone feels it can be improved upon, the question can be reopened imo.

Comment: Yes, adding what you've tried so far is pretty mandatory for a good SO quesiton

Comment: I didn't think of it until a few minutes ago.  I'll definitely go add it to the question now.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: a minor simplification of your function is: `sz = ceiling(log(n)/log(26)); do.call(CJ, replicate(sz, LETTERS, simplify = F))[, Reduce(paste0, .SD)][1:n]`

Comment: Or `do.call(CJ, replicate((n - 1) %/% 26 + 1, LETTERS, simplify = FALSE))[, do.call(paste0, .SD)][1:n]`

Comment: The difference between yours and mine other than efficiency (my answer from @DavidArenburg's link) is that mine does single letters `A B C`, then doubles, then triples, etc., whereas yours will have the same number of characters per string - `myfunc(27)` begins with `"AA", "AB", ...`

Comment: The most efficient way to use this is probably to run it once to create a look-up table (a keyed data table) rather than computing letter mappings on the fly.

Comment: See, also, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876755/is-there-a-way-to-extend-letters-past-26-characters-e-g-aa-ab-ac)

Comment: Expanding on @eddi's suggestion: `ifelse(n < 27, LETTERS[1:n], c(LETTERS, do.call(CJ, replicate(sz, LETTERS, simplify = F))[, Reduce(paste0, .SD)][27:n]))` which includes single letters at the start of a sequence.

Comment: variation of @eddi.  Does not use any packages. `sz <- ceiling(log(n) / log(26)); g <- expand.grid(rep(list(LETTERS), sz))[sz:1];
do.call(paste0, g)[1:n]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several nice solutions were posted in the comments already. Only the solution posted by @Gregor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25878840/2204410) is currently giving the preferred solution by Ben.

However, the methods posted by @eddi, @DavidArenburg and @G.Grothendieck can be adapted to get the prefered outcome as well:

```
# adaptation of @eddi's method:
library(data.table)
n  <- 29
sz  <- ceiling(log(n)/log(26))
do.call(CJ, replicate(sz, c("", LETTERS), simplify = F))[-1, unique(Reduce(paste0, .SD))][1:n]

# adaptation of @DavidArenburg's method:
n <- 29
list(LETTERS, c(LETTERS, do.call(CJ, replicate((n - 1) %/% 26 + 1, LETTERS, simplify = FALSE))[, do.call(paste0, .SD)][1:(n-26)])[[(n>26)+1]]

# adaptation of @G.Grothendieck's method:
n  <- 29
sz  <- ceiling(log(n)/log(26))
g <- expand.grid(c('',LETTERS), rep(LETTERS, (sz-1)))
g <- g[order(g$Var1),]
do.call(paste0, g)[1:n]
```

All three result in:

```
 [1] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  "K"  "L"  "M"  "N"  "O" 
[16] "P"  "Q"  "R"  "S"  "T"  "U"  "V"  "W"  "X"  "Y"  "Z"  "AA" "AB" "AC"
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems like an awesome candidate for `Rcpp`. Below is the very simple approach:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
StringVector combVec(CharacterVector x, CharacterVector y) {
    int nx = x.size();
    int ny = y.size();
    CharacterVector z(nx*ny);
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
            z[k] = x[i];
            z[k] += y[j];
            k++;
        }
    }
    return z;  
}

NumChar <- function(n) {
    t <- trunc(log(n, 26))
    ch <- LETTERS
    for (i in t:1L) {ch <- combVec(ch, LETTERS)}
    ch[1:n]
}
```

The result is exactly what the OP's answer returns.

```
library(data.table)
Rcpp::sourceCpp('combVec.cpp')

identical(myfunc(100000), NumChar(100000))
[1] TRUE 

head(NumChar(100000))
[1] "AAAA" "AAAB" "AAAC" "AAAD" "AAAE" "AAAF"
tail(NumChar(100000))
[1] "FRXY" "FRXZ" "FRYA" "FRYB" "FRYC" "FRYD"
```

**Updated** benchmarks including @eddi's excellent `Rcpp` implementation:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(myfunc(10000), funEddi(10000), NumChar(10000), excelCols(10000, LETTERS))
Unit: microseconds
                     expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval  cld
            myfunc(10000)  6632.125  7255.454  8441.7770  7912.4780  9283.660 14184.971   100   c 
           funEddi(10000) 12012.673 12869.928 15296.3838 13870.7050 16425.907 80443.142   100    d
           NumChar(10000)  2592.555  2883.394  3326.9292  3167.4995  3574.300  6051.273   100  b  
excelCols(10000, LETTERS)   636.165   656.820   782.7679   716.9225   811.148  1386.673   100 a 

microbenchmark(myfunc(100000), funEddi(100000), NumChar(100000), excelCols(100000, LETTERS), times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
                     expr        min         lq       mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
            myfunc(1e+05) 203.992591 210.049303 255.049395 220.74955 262.52141 397.03521    10   c 
           funEddi(1e+05) 523.934475 530.646483 563.853995 552.83903 577.88915 688.84714    10    d
           NumChar(1e+05)  82.216802  83.546577  97.615537  93.63809 112.14316 115.84911    10  b  
excelCols(1e+05, LETTERS)   7.480882   8.377266   9.562554   8.93254  11.10519  14.11631    10 a
```

As @DirkEddelbuettel says *"Rcpp is not some magic pony..."*. These discrepancies in efficiency just show that although `Rcpp`, or any package for that matter, is super awesome, they won't fix crappy code. Thanks @eddi for posting a proper `Rcpp` implementation.

Comment: this is good, but I naively would've expected at least a 10x improvement from an Rcpp solution...

Comment: @eddi, I agree, I was expecting more of an improvement, however, I'm never surprised by the power of `data.table`.  Additionally, the elegance of the `data.table` solutions are off the chart.  Many kudos!!

Comment: @eddi I would also like to add that I still have a lot to learn about `C++` and `Rcpp` in general. Instead of saying "Below is the very simple approach", I should have said "Below is a hack from a super rookie".

Comment: understood :) I added another Rcpp solution that's a bit faster.

Comment: @eddi, a bit faster is an understatement.  Your `Rcpp` implementation is up to `10x` faster than mine... Very Nice!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fast `Rcpp` solution which will be orders of magnitude faster than native R solutions:

```
cppFunction('CharacterVector excelCols(int n, CharacterVector x) {
  CharacterVector res(n);
  int sz = x.size();
  std::string base;
  int baseN[100] = {0}; // being lazy about size here - you will never grow larger than this
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    bool incr = false;
    for (int j = base.size() - 1; j >= 0 && !incr; --j) {
      if (baseN[j] == sz) {
        baseN[j] = 1;
        base[j] = as<std::string>(x[0])[0];
      } else {
        baseN[j] += 1;
        base[j] = as<std::string>(x[baseN[j] - 1])[0];
        incr = true;
      }
    }
    if (!incr) {
      baseN[base.size()] = 1;
      base += x[0];
    }
    res[i] = base;
  }
  return res;
}')

excelCols(100, LETTERS)
```